# Create a RasterStack from a list

Tags: r, image, stack, layer

I have image data stored in a list. The file contains 1000 lists (corresponding to the pixels), each list containing a vector of 44 entities. Now I want to create a RasterStack data type in order to use this data for the mesma function. The stack data should have 44 layers.

```
example_data = replicate(1000, rnorm(44, 8, 1),simplify = FALSE)
stack(example_data, bands = 44)
```

I get the following error message.

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what you mean with a "list file". I suppose you mean "list" (as in your example).

Let's make a simpler example. A list with one element for each cell (4 cells in total). Each element has a vector (one value for each layer; there are 3 layers )

```
d <- replicate(4, 1:3,simplify = FALSE)
d
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3
# etc
```

Change this to a matrix, with a row for each cell

```
m <- matrix(unlist(d), nrow=4, byrow=TRUE)
m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    1    2    3
#[3,]    1    2    3
#[4,]    1    2    3
```

Create an appropriate Raster* object

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(nrow=2, ncol=2, nl=3)
```

And assign the values

```
values(b) <- m 
b
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 2, 2, 4, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 180, 90  (x, y)
#extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#source     : memory
#names      : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3 
#min values :       1,       2,       3 
#max values :       1,       2,       3
```